# create-react-app build process take too long

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, create-react-app

We received from a partner a  front end to interact with our API (builed in node.js) builded using create-create-app, after cloning the repo from our partner git,
the `npm start` command works, I can locally test the app interacting with the API with no problems at all.
also in my local machine the `npm run build` command works great, im able to build and run the app with `serve build` command.

the problem comes after cloning the repo into the Amazon AWS EC2 instance, im able to clone the repo but after running `npm install`, when running `npm run build` the process just stay forever in the following message:

```
sudo npm run build

> sensores@0.1.0 build /var/www/smartdots-frontend
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
```

after 20 minutes or so the process keep hanged and lastly this is the final message:

```
> sensores@0.1.0 build /var/www/smartdots-frontend
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sensores@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sensores@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2019-01-12T21_26_31_254Z-debug.log
```

Finally, this is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v11.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~prebuild: sensores@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: sensores@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/smartdots-frontend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: CWD: /var/www/smartdots-frontend
10 silly lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle sensores@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: sensores@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid sensores@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/smartdots-frontend
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-1069-aws
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v11.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error sensores@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the sensores@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tested the `npm run build` in several machines, with different OS, and it always run fine, in really desperated about this, i've tried building the app as root, changing folder permissions and ownership, and nothing works, building the app in another computer and serve it in the AWS machine also doesn't work

```
 node --version
v11.6.0

 npm --version
6.5.0

create-react-app --version
2.1.3
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sensores",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.11.3",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "pm2": "^3.2.8",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-draggable": "^3.1.1",
    "react-form": "^3.5.6",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "recharts": "^1.4.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^10.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "json-server --watch ./serverfake.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does sounds like it's a memory issue, particularly this line:

`The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called`kill -9`on the process.`.

You can check it by running the command `top` inside the terminal and see the memory usage.

Comment: Hello buddy, thanks for your reply, this is the output of the top command:
https://ibb.co/Cmr9gRJ

Can yoy tell if there is anything wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like you have ~110MB available in the RAM, to my experience that's too few for larger apps (the node process that you're running consumes just around that).

You can prove that it is a memory issue by running the top as you run the script in another terminal window. If the Kib "Free" memory part reaches zero (or close), then you will need to increase the available RAM to get the command running.

Comment: Helly! Thanks again for your repply, i've managed to finally compile the project, you were right.

I've stopper every running app and compiled the create-react-app once again and it worked

Could I just increase the swap to solve this problem? or illl need to add more memory? Shutting down all process everytime I need to deploy a new version of the react-act is not convenient right now

Comment: Glad to hear! You'll need to add more RAM to solve the issue. Please mark my answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: Done! very thanks for your answer, we created another machine with more RAM! thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It worked with increasing more and more memory. `npm` is really memory heavy build.